# TYPO3 external authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, typo3

We have a TYPO3 CMS to manage user base and as a portal for various user-specific information.  We also have a separate ASP.net C# application used for charting visualization with many of the same users with a separate admin backend .  Looking to get rid of login portion ASP.net application and use TYPO3 session authentication.  Idea is for the user to be able to click a link within their Typo3 frontend and get directed to the ASP.net application which can then authenticate with the Typo3 session and act in accordance.  Just wondering if my best bet is to write something in the ASP.net app to get the TYPO3 session cookie (is that possible?) or if I have to do something clunky like oauth2/other service

Answer (score 0):

I would write a TYPO3 authentication service that contacts your ASP.NET app via one of known protocols (REST?) or even custom protocol and checks authentication. If it is successful, the normal TYPO3 authentication process goes on.

It is not enough to simply set a cookie during the authentication. There are other things that has to be done for the user to be "set up" as logged in.

Comment: As far as I understand he wants it reverse: the ASP application should use the TYPO3 users. in an optimal version: just use the TYPO3 cookie to detect a valid login.

Comment: What stops me from faking a cookie?

Comment: probably in the same way as TYPO3 does not depend on a cookie only: the cookie represents a session cookie where the login information is stored and verified on each server request. In this way the ASP application needs to call the TYPO3 installation to verify the login.

Comment: Correct, I do want it in reverse-- ASP.net should use typo users. ASP.net backend will still have some user specific information but would  link to typo ideally on username and another unique ID via the cookie.  I guess my question was if I could read the typo3 session cookie without having to call back to the typo3 installation to parse it back.  I assume the flow would be: ASP.net page reads the cookie, sends it back to a typo3 service/function, then typo3 function returns whatever parameters I want authenticate with ASP.net.  Just didn't know if someone had done this before.